In Finacle 10, I am creating custom menu so, I want some explanation of cri_ginc.jsp file code. I am attaching screenshot of the code below
I am creating custom menu so in Finacle 10. Give me important explanation of path and some keywords that I have used in my code. You can see the whole code below in the screenshot that have been attached.
I am creating custom menu so in Finacle 10. Give me important explanation of path and some keywords that I have used in my code.
